# Wheel of Fortune game - follow-up

Tags: javascript, game

After posting [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/12197/3163) I made some updates and changes to my code. My new demo for the game is located [here](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/XP9Qv/). Right now it is only one player.

Is there anything I could improve on in the code?

```
Array.prototype.randomize = function () {
    //fisher yates from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/12200/3163
    var i = this.length;
    if (i === 0) return false;
    while (--i) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var tempi = this[i];
        var tempj = this[j];
        this[i] = tempj;
        this[j] = tempi;
    }
};

Array.prototype.toObject = function () {
    var o = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        o[this[i]] = '';
    }
    return o;
};

function bindEvent(el, eventName, eventHandler) {
    if (el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler, false);
    } else if (el.attachEvent) {
        el.attachEvent('on' + eventName, eventHandler);
    }
}


var Wheel = (function () {
    var wheel = document.getElementById('wheel'),
        wheelValues = [5000, 600, 500, 300, 500, 800, 550, 400, 300, 900, 500, 300, 900, 0, 600, 400, 300, -2, 800, 350, 450, 700, 300, 600],
        spinTimeout = false,
        spinModifier = function () {
            return Math.random() * 10 + 20;
        },
        modifier = spinModifier(),
        slowdownSpeed = 0.5,
        prefix = (function () {
            if (document.body.style.MozTransform !== undefined) {
                return "MozTransform";
            } else if (document.body.style.WebkitTransform !== undefined) {
                return "WebkitTransform";
            } else if (document.body.style.OTransform !== undefined) {
                return "OTransform";
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }()),
        degreeToRadian = function (deg) {
            return deg / (Math.PI * 180);
        };

    function Wheel() {}

    Wheel.prototype.rotate = function (degrees) {
        var val = "rotate(-" + degrees + "deg)";
        if (wheel.style[prefix] !== undefined) wheel.style[prefix] = val;
        var rad = degreeToRadian(degrees % 360),
            filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=" + rad + ", M12=-" + rad + ", M21=" + rad + ", M22=" + rad + ")";
        if (wheel.style.filter !== undefined) wheel.style.filter = filter;
        wheel.setAttribute("data-rotation", degrees);
    };

    Wheel.prototype.spin = function (callback, amount) {
        var _this = this;
        clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
        modifier -= slowdownSpeed;
        if (amount === undefined) {
            amount = parseInt(wheel.getAttribute('data-rotation'), 10);
        }
        this.rotate(amount);
        if (modifier > 0) {
            spinTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                _this.spin(callback, amount + modifier);
            }, 1000 / 5);
        } else {
            var dataRotation = parseInt(wheel.getAttribute('data-rotation'), 10);
            modifier = spinModifier();
            var divider = 360 / wheelValues.length;
            var offset = divider / 2; //half division
            var wheelValue = wheelValues[Math.floor(Math.ceil((dataRotation + offset) % 360) / divider)];
            switch (wheelValue) {
                case 0:
                    return callback(0);
                case -1:
                    return callback("Free Spin");
                case -2:
                    return callback("Lose a turn");
                default:
                    return callback(wheelValue);
            }
        }
    };

    return Wheel;
})();

var WheelGame = (function () {
    var wheel = new Wheel(),
        vowels = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'],
        spinWheel = document.getElementById('spin'),
        buyVowel = document.getElementById('vowel'),
        displayArea = document.getElementById('display'),
        newButton = document.getElementById('newpuzzle'),
        money = document.getElementById('money'),
        solve = document.getElementById('solve');

    function WheelGame(puzzles) {
        var _this = this;
        this.puzzles = puzzles;
        this.puzzles.randomize();
        this.currentMoney = 0;
        this.puzzleSolved = false;

        bindEvent(buyVowel, "click", function () {
            if (_this.currentMoney > 200) {
                if (_this.createGuessPrompt("PLEASE ENTER A VOWEL", true) !== false) {
                    _this.currentMoney -= 200;
                    _this.updateMoney();
                }
            } else {
                alert("You need more than $200 to buy a vowel");
            }
        });
        bindEvent(newButton, "click", function () {
            _this.newRound();
        });
        var spinTheWheel = function () {
            wheel.spin(function (valueSpun) {
                if (isNaN(valueSpun)) {
                    alert(valueSpun);
                } else {
                    //is a valid number
                    if (valueSpun === 0) {
                        alert('Bankrupt!');
                        _this.currentMoney = 0;
                    } else {
                        //spun greater than 0
                        var amountFound = _this.createGuessPrompt(valueSpun);
                        _this.currentMoney += (valueSpun * amountFound);
                    }
                    _this.updateMoney();
                }
            });
        };
        bindEvent(spinWheel, "click", spinTheWheel);
        bindEvent(wheel, "click", spinTheWheel);

        function arrays_equal(a, b) {
            return !(a < b || b < a);
        }

        bindEvent(solve, "click", function () {
            if (!_this.puzzleSolved) {
                var solve = prompt("Solve the puzzle?", "");
                if (solve) {
                    guess = solve.toUpperCase().split("");
                    if (arrays_equal(guess, _this.currentPuzzleArray)) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < guess.length; ++i) {
                            _this.guessLetter(guess[i], false, true);
                        }
                    }
                    if (!_this.puzzleSolved) {
                        alert('PUZZLE NOT SOLVED');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        this.startRound(0); //start the 1st round
    }

    WheelGame.prototype.updateMoney = function () {
        money.innerHTML = this.currentMoney;
    };

    WheelGame.prototype.guessLetter = function (guess, isVowel, solvingPuzzle) {
        var timesFound = 0;
        solvingPuzzle = solvingPuzzle === undefined ? false : true;
        //find it:
        if (guess.length && !this.puzzleSolved) {
            if (!solvingPuzzle && !isVowel && (guess in vowels.toObject())) {
                alert("Cannot guess a vowel right now!");
                return false;
            }
            if (!solvingPuzzle && isVowel && !(guess in vowels.toObject())) {
                alert("Cannot guess a consanant right now!");
                return false;
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < this.currentPuzzleArray.length; ++i) {
                if (guess == this.currentPuzzleArray[i]) {
                    var span = document.getElementById("letter" + i);
                    if (span.innerHTML != guess) {
                        //found it
                        ++timesFound;
                    }
                    span.innerHTML = guess;
                    if (guess in this.lettersInPuzzle.toObject() && !(guess in this.guessedArray.toObject())) {
                        this.guessedArray.push(guess);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (this.guessedArray.length == this.lettersInPuzzle.length) {
                alert("PUZZLE SOLVED!");
                this.puzzleSolved = true;
            }

            return timesFound;
        }
        return false;

    };

    var guessTimes = 0;
    WheelGame.prototype.createGuessPrompt = function (valueSpun, isVowel) {
        isVowel = isVowel === undefined ? false : true;
        if (!this.puzzleSolved) {
            var letter;
            if (isVowel) {
                letter = prompt("PLEASE ENTER A VOWEL", "");
            } else {
                letter = prompt("YOU SPUN A " + valueSpun + " PLEASE ENTER A CONSONANT", "");
            }
            if (letter) {
                var guess = letter.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
                var timesFound = this.guessLetter(guess, isVowel);
                if (timesFound === false) {
                    ++guessTimes;
                    if (guessTimes < 5) {
                        return this.createGuessPrompt(valueSpun, isVowel);
                    }
                }
                guessTimes = 0;
                return timesFound;
            } else {
                ++guessTimes;
                if (guessTimes < 5) {
                    return this.createGuessPrompt(valueSpun, isVowel);
                }
                else {
                    // reset guessTimes
                    guessTimes = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    };

    WheelGame.prototype.newRound = function () {
        var round = ++this.round;
        if (round < this.puzzles.length) {
            while (displayArea.hasChildNodes()) { //remove old puzzle
                displayArea.removeChild(displayArea.firstChild);
            }
            this.startRound(round);
        } else {
            alert("No more puzzles!");
        }
    };

    WheelGame.prototype.startRound = function (round) {
        this.round = round;
        this.lettersInPuzzle = [];
        this.guessedArray = [];
        this.puzzleSolved = false;
        this.currentPuzzle = this.puzzles[this.round].toUpperCase();
        this.currentPuzzleArray = this.currentPuzzle.split("");
        var currentPuzzleArray = this.currentPuzzleArray;
        var lettersInPuzzle = this.lettersInPuzzle;
        var word = document.createElement('div');
        displayArea.appendChild(word);
        word.className = "word";
        for (var i = 0; i < currentPuzzleArray.length; ++i) {
            var span = document.createElement('div');
            span.className = "wordLetter ";

            if (currentPuzzleArray[i] != " ") {
                span.className += "letter";
                if (!(currentPuzzleArray[i] in lettersInPuzzle.toObject())) {
                    lettersInPuzzle.push(currentPuzzleArray[i]);
                }
                word.appendChild(span);
            } else {
                span.className += "space";
                word = document.createElement('div');
                displayArea.appendChild(word);
                word.className = "word";
                word.appendChild(span);
                word = document.createElement('div');
                displayArea.appendChild(word);
                word.className = "word";
            }

            span.id = "letter" + i;
        }

        var clear = document.createElement('div');
        displayArea.appendChild(clear);
        clear.className = "clear";
    };

    return WheelGame;
})();

var Game = new WheelGame([
    "doctor who", "the dark knight rises", "wheel of fortune",
    "facebook", "twitter", "google plus", "sea world", "pastrami on rye",
    "i am sparta", "whose line is it anyway", "google chrome"
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Especially as you develop the programme you will probably want to separate out the game logic from the parts that update different parts of the display or take user input. For instance you can have a separate object controlling the display of the letters:

```
var WordDisplay = (function () {
    var display = document.getElementById('display'),
        characters;

    function WordDisplay(puzzle) {
        while (display.hasChildNodes()) { //remove old puzzle
            display.removeChild(display.firstChild);
        }
        var word = div(display, 'word');
        characters = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < puzzle.length; ++i) {
            if (puzzle[i] == ' ') {
                characters.push(div(display, 'space'));
                word = div(display, 'word');
            } else {
                characters.push(div(word, 'letter'));
            }
        }
        div(display, 'clear');
    }
    WordDisplay.prototype.showLetter = function (i, letter) {
        characters[i].innerHTML = letter;
    };
    return WordDisplay;
})();

function div(parent, className) {
    var r = document.createElement('div');
    r.className = className;
    parent.appendChild(r);
    return r;
}
```

You then use `wordDisplay = new WordDisplay(puzzleArray)` to initiate the board and `wordDisplay.showLetter(3, 'x')` to place the letter x at position 3. This will help to shorten the main `WheelGame` code and make the whole thing easier to read and debug. (http://jsfiddle.net/9ZXX7/4/)

Note some other changes made there:

- simplifying the lines that display the puzzle and removing the reliance on element `id`s
- using a helper function `div` to make building html elements less repetitive
- slightly simplified the method `WheelGame.prototype.guessLetter`

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot of code to review so it might be a good idea to break it down into separate parts. This way it'll be easier to give a more detailed and tailored review. But anyways here are a few things you can do that should help your performance:

**Minimize Paints and Reflows** - Might seem like an obvious one but it's one of the most important. Especially in your `rotate` function which from what I can tell does most of the animation grunt work. An easy way to optimize this is if you need to read data from the page, read it all at once, then repaint/edit layout.

**Save yourself some code** - There are a few spot where you can bring down the size by joining operations. Something like this:

```
var word = document.createElement('div');
        displayArea.appendChild(word);
        word.className = "word";
```

Could be written in one line:

```
displayArea.appendChild(document.createElement("div")).className = "word";
```

Since `.appendChild()` returns the appended node, you can chain. I would suggest you go through and try to spot these yourself.

**Cache Array Lengths** - The loop is undoubtedly one of the most important parts related to JavaScript performance. Try to optimize the logic inside a loop so that each iteration is done efficiently.

One way to do this is to store the size of the array that will be covered, so it doesn't need to be recalculated every time the loop is iterated.

For example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < currentPuzzleArray.length; ++i) {
```

Could be done like so:

```
for (var i = 0, len = currentPuzzleArray.length; i < len ; ++i) {
```

[This jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/browser-diet-cache-array-length/10) can demonstrate what I mean by this. In most of the modern browsers this is less of a problem, but is evident in the older ones.

Comment: The array length issue is minimal. I am not the best fan of "chaining" unless it is really needed -- but it looks cool :-P

Anything else?

(Also I have no idea how to break my code into multiple questions)

Comment: @Neal you can open different questions and link back to this one. Each question with a smaller snippet that you want to focus on and get reviewed. Another thing is you might want to look into an alternative solution to displaying information and getting input rather than using alerts.

Comment: @Neal it's understandable that some snippets can't be separated from others that's why you should link back here for "the full code". You can separate the parts you think need work on and start with those.

Comment: Multiple questions that all go to the same point are still all the same question -- there is no need for multiple questions asking the same thing -- I am looking for a review on the whole of the code. Aside -- The alerts are annoying, yes, I am trying to replace them, I am just looking for a non-jQuery esque solution (trying to be library lite)

Comment: In response to your second comment -- I am looking for a review on the full code and not just on bits and pieces of it.