# Wheel of Fortune -- The ES6 Version

Tags: javascript, game, ecmascript-6

I have taken my original code from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/28973/3163) and turned it into an es6 version of the same game.

Any code review and critiques are useful.

*Side note*: "Bankrupt" and "Lose a Turn" do not do anything right now as it is a non-multiplayer game right now and I do not think it adds anything to the dynamic, but the wheel I have has those values.

Here is a jsfiddle link to play with https://jsfiddle.net/maniator/4azoqbpv/59/

```js
class OnListener {
  constructor() {
    this.events = {};
  }

  on(event, callback) {
    this.events[event] = callback.bind(this);
  }

  trigger(event, ...value) {
    if (Object.keys(this.events).includes('all')) {
      return this.events['all'](event, ...value);
    }

    for (let _event in this.events) {
      if (event.indexOf(_event) > -1 || _event.indexOf(event) > 1) {
        this.events[_event](event, ...value);
      }
    }
  }
}

class Wheel extends OnListener {
  constructor({
    element,
    button,
    values = []
  }) {
    super();

    this.element = element;
    this.values = values;
    this.modifier = Wheel.spinModifier();
    this.slowdownSpeed = 0.5;
    this.currentRotation = 0;
    this.spinTimeout = null;
    
    const clickFn = this.click.bind(this);

    element.addEventListener('click', clickFn, false);
    button.addEventListener('click', clickFn, false);
  }

  static spinModifier() {
    return Math.random() * 10 + 20;
  }

  stop() {
    clearTimeout(this.spinTimeout);
  }

  click() {
    this.trigger('spin:start');
    return this.spin().then((value) => {
      this.trigger('spin:end', value);

      return value;
    });
  }

  rotate(degrees) {
    this.element.style.transform = `rotate(-${degrees}deg)`;
    this.currentRotation = degrees;
    return this;
  }

  spin(amount = this.currentRotation, modifier = this.modifier) {
    this.stop();
    modifier -= this.slowdownSpeed;
    this.rotate(amount);

    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      if (modifier > 0) {
        this.spinTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
          res(this.spin(amount + modifier, modifier));
        }, 1000 / 5)
      } else {
        const dataRotation = this.currentRotation;
        const divider = 360 / this.values.length;
        const offset = divider / 2; // half division
        const wheelValue = this.values[Math.floor(Math.ceil((dataRotation + offset) % 360) / divider)];

        this.modifier = Wheel.spinModifier();

        switch (wheelValue) {
          case 0:
            return res(0);
          case -1:
            return res("Free Spin");
          case -2:
            return res("Lose a turn");
          default:
            return res(wheelValue);
        }
      }
    })
  }
}

class Board extends OnListener {
  static randomize(arr) {
    //fisher yates from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/12200/3163
    let i = arr.length;
    if (i === 0) return [];
    while (--i) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      const tempi = arr[i];
      const tempj = arr[j];
      arr[i] = tempj;
      arr[j] = tempi;
    }

    return arr;
  }

  constructor({
    answers = [],
    element,
    button
  }) {
    super();

    this.element = element;
    this.answers = Board.randomize(answers);
    this.currentBoard = -1;

    button.addEventListener('click', () => this.next(), false);
  }

  clear() {
    const displayArea = this.element;

    while (displayArea.hasChildNodes()) { //remove old puzzle
      displayArea.removeChild(displayArea.firstChild);
    }
  }

  solve(solution) {
    return (this.answers[this.currentBoard].toUpperCase() === solution.toUpperCase());
  }

  getNextBoard() {
    try {
      const board = this.answers[++this.currentBoard].toUpperCase();
      const boardArray = board.split('');

      this.trigger('new:puzzle', board);

      return boardArray;
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error('No more levels!');
    }
  }

  inputLetter(_letter) {
    let count = 0;

    this.letters.forEach((obj) => {
      const {
        letter,
        element
      } = obj;
      if (!obj.seen && _letter === letter) {
        element.textContent = letter;
        obj.seen = true;
        count += 1;
      }
    });

    return count;
  }

  next() {
    const boardArray = this.getNextBoard();
    const displayArea = this.element;

    this.clear();

    this.letters = [];

    let word = document.createElement('div');

    word.classList.add('word');

    const words = boardArray.reduce((words, currentLetter, index) => {
      const letter = document.createElement('div');
      letter.classList.add('wordLetter');
      letter.id = `letter_${index}`;

      if (currentLetter !== ' ') {
        letter.classList.add('letter');
        this.letters.push({
          letter: currentLetter,
          element: letter
        });

        word.appendChild(letter);
      } else {
        words.push(word);
        word = document.createElement('div');
        word.classList.add('word');
      }

      return words;
    }, []);

    // push the last one
    words.push(word);

    words.forEach((wordElement) => {
      displayArea.appendChild(wordElement);
    });
  }
}

class Game {
  constructor({
    wheel,
    board,
    vowelButton,
    solveButton,
    moneyElement
  }) {
    this.wheel = wheel;
    this.board = board;
    this.vowels = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'];
    this.totalScore = 0;
    this.moneyElement = moneyElement;

    vowelButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (this.totalScore >= 100) {
        this.totalScore -= 100;
        this.guessLetter(0, true);
      } else {
        // @todo an else case
      }
    }, false);

    solveButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const solution = prompt('What is the solution?');
      if (board.solve(solution)) {
        solution.split('').forEach((letter) => {
          this.board.inputLetter(letter.toUpperCase())
        });
        setTimeout(() => alert('Puzzle solved!'), 10);
      } else {
        alert('Puzzle not solved!');
      }
    }, false);
  }

  start() {
    this.listen();
    this.board.next();
  }

  guessLetter(value, asVowel = false) {
    const letter = prompt(`Guess a ${asVowel ? 'vowel' : 'letter'}`);

    try {
      if (!(/^[a-zA-Z]$/.test(letter))) {
        throw new Error('Must input an actual letter A-Z');
      }

      const capitalLetter = letter.toUpperCase();
      const letterIsVowel = this.vowels.includes(capitalLetter);

      if (asVowel && !letterIsVowel) {
        throw new Error(`Must input a vowel: [${this.vowels.join(', ')}]`);
      } else if (!asVowel && letterIsVowel) {
        throw new Error(`Cannot input a vowel: [${this.vowels.join(', ')}]`);
      }

      const count = this.board.inputLetter(capitalLetter);

      console.log(`Found ${letter} ${count} times worth $${value * count}`);

      if (!asVowel) {
        this.totalScore += (value * count);
      }

      this.moneyElement.textContent = this.totalScore;
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
      this.guessLetter(...arguments);
    }
  }

  listen() {
    this.wheel.on('spin:end', (event, value) => {
      if (isNaN(value) || value === 0) {
        console.log('SPUN SOMETHING BAD', value);
      } else {
        console.log('CAN GUESS A LETTER', value);
        this.guessLetter(value);
      }
    });
    this.board.on('new:puzzle', (event, ...value) => {
      console.log(`${event} ${value}`);
      this.wheel.stop();
    });
  }
}

const wheel = new Wheel({
  element: document.getElementById('wheel'),
  values: [5000, 600, 500, 300, 500, 800, 550, 400, 300, 900, 500, 300, 900, 0, 600, 400, 300, -2, 800, 350, 450, 700, 300, 600],
  button: document.getElementById('spin'),
});

const board = new Board({
  element: document.getElementById('display'),
  answers: [
    "doctor who", "the dark knight rises", "wheel of fortune",
    "facebook", "twitter", "google plus", "sea world", "pastrami on rye",
    "i am sparta", "whose line is it anyway", "google chrome"
  ],
  button: document.getElementById('newpuzzle')
});

const game = new Game({
  wheel,
  board,
  vowelButton: document.getElementById('vowel'),
  solveButton: document.getElementById('solve'),
  moneyElement: document.getElementById('money')
});

game.start();

console.log(game);
```

```css
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Changa+One);
#game {
  font-family: 'Changa One' serif;
}

#wheel {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 500px;
  -moz-border-radius: 250px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 250px;
  border-radius: 250px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s linear;
  -opera-transition: -opera-transform 0.5s linear;
  -ms-transition: transform 0.5s linear;
}

#tick {
  margin-left: 244px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

#display {
  background-color: #43759f;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: 4px double #fff;
}

#display div.word {
  display: inline-block;
}
#display div.word:not(:first-child) {
  padding: 0 30px;
}

#display div.wordLetter {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 65px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 2px solid #43759f;
  float: left;
  line-height: 65px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

#display div.wordLetter.letter {
  border-color: #eee;
}

#playArea {
  clear: both;
}

#playArea button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 1000;
  border: 4px double #fff;
  background-color: #43759f;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  color: white;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

#playArea #moneyArea {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px black solid;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="game">
    <div id="display"></div>
    <div id="playArea">
        <button id="spin">spin wheel</button>
        <button id="vowel">buy vowel</button>
        <button id="solve">solve puzzle</button>
        <button id="newpuzzle">new puzzle</button>
        <div id="moneyArea">
            Score: $<span id="money">0</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="tick">⇩</div>
    <img id="wheel" src="//i.imgur.com/R7JYazp.png" data-rotation="0" />
</div>
```

Comment: I've never seen this form before `constructor({
    element,
    button,
    values = []
  })`. What is that? Doesn't look valid to me.

Comment: That is valid es6 and also now valid JavaScript @Xotic750 :-) Otherwise none of it would work

Comment: Can you point me at some documentation? I though perhaps it was new with [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters), but I don't see this pattern there. And my linter configured for ES6 also points at this construction.

Comment: Ok I have found it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Ha sorry I was on a train @Xotic750 Yea it is object destructuring :-)

Comment: I don't really know all the rules for wof, but I assume Bankrupt makes your money go to 0. Nothing happened for me when it landed there, though.

Comment: @mjr That has not been coded in as there is no multiplayer (yet) I did not feel it was ness yet.

Comment: Oh! Fair enough

Comment: @mjr I have added a note to the original post stating that now, Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

In no particular order:

- the `OnListener` class should be called `EventEmitter`, that's the known convention (and it is also used by Node).
- Your `this.events` should be a `Map`, then you can iterate it with `for..of`:

  ```
    trigger(event, ...value) {
      if (this.events.has('all')) {
        return this.events.get('all')(event, ...value);
      }

      for (let [name, fn] of this.events) {
        if (event.includes(name) || name.includes(event)) {
          fn(event, ...value);
        }
      }
    }
  ```
- On that note, if you have an event called `'all'` the `trigger()` function will return early, and the actual event won't be triggered.
- `return Math.random() * 10 + 20;` magic numbers are magic.
- `this.spinTimeout = setTimeout(() => ..., 1000 / 5)` more magic numbers
- `const wheelValue = this.values[Math.floor(Math.ceil((dataRotation + offset) % 360) / divider)];` I don't even know how to read that, let alone what it means.
- Your static randomizer function can be implemented as an iterator function, for better readability:

  ```
  static function* randomize(arr) {
    let copy = [...arr]; // don't modify the original!
    while (copy.length > 0) {
      const randIndex = ~~(Math.random() * copy.length);
      yield copy.splice(randIndex, 1)[0]; // remove random element and yield it.
    }
  }
  ```

  Then use it at either `for..of` or like so: `this.answers = [...Board.randomize(answers);]`
- When you see this:

  ```
  let count = 0;

  this.letters.forEach((obj) => {
      // somewhere inside
      count += 1;
    }
  });

  return count;
  ```

  You want `reduce`.
- This
      catch (error) {
        // snip
        this.guessLetter(...arguments);
      }
  means I can't drop the guess by pressing "Cancel".
- `#playArea #moneyArea` two IDs are redundant. `#moneyArea` should do just fine.

### The more general things

- Both your `Game` class and your `Board` class have presentation mixed in their logic. (They both access the DOM and do processing)
- Having just events is a good way to define what a component can or cannot do. Having just methods is a good way to make the component readable and clear. Having both is a mess.
- Using Exceptions as flow control is a Bad Thing<sup>TM</sup>, it's akin to using Ye Olde `goto` Of The Dark Times.

Comment: I know about the exception part. I have not come up with a good way to handle errors are show the prompts etc (using native is inherently "bad". The HTML/CSS was copied over from my old example and I did not really change it much, but thank you for going over it :-) . So Can the "randomize" function you created be called `getNextPuzzle`? Also I thought yield etc were not fully fleshed out in es6?

Comment: Iterators are fully in the spec in ES6. you can see it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/ypgs707j/

Comment: Nice catch on the `all` bug! I did not see that one!